# Program stops working when calling kernel too many times

Tags: c, cuda, driver

I am doing particles simulations with Self-propelled particles. My CUDA kernel updates each particle's location at every time step. So I run CUDA kernel from the for loop. Schematically it looks like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<NumberOfTimeSteps;i++)
    Calculate<<<1,N,sharedsize>>>(float *data, other parameters)
    Cudamemcpy(data_cpu,data,...);
    WriteToFile(data_cpu);
end
```

So, each time step new data is calculated based on previously calculated data. It works ok, when `NumberOfTimeSteps` is small. But after I set NumberOfTimeSteps > 500 (approximate critical value), program stops working.

I know, that there is a limitation on kernel execution: driver can stop GPU calculations if kernel execution time is too long. However, in my code, time of the single kernel execution doesn't change with  `NumberOfTimeSteps`.

Is there any limitations on the number of kernel calls?

Thanks

EDIT: There was another issue: I didn't close mat files (where I put results), and kept opening new files each step. That eventually caused error. I voted to close question, since it has nothing to do with CUDA. Robert answered alredy about CUDA kernels.

Comment: What does "not working" mean, *exactly*? Does the API return any errors? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any limitations on the number of kernel calls?

There is no real limit to the number of kernel calls.  There is a limit to how many can be accepted asynchronously, but after this limit, additional kernel calls will simply block the CPU thread from proceeding until some queue slots open up (i.e. until some previously issued kernels complete).

If your program is failing after ~500 kernel calls, it is due to some other issue, which is impossible to diagnose based on what you have shown in your question.

If by "program stops working" you mean that you hit a WDDM timeout, then it is possible based on batched kernel calls within WDDM, that even though a single kernel call is not longer than the timeout period, back-to-back kernel calls may exceed the watchdog timeout.    This really should not be happening in your case, because `cudaMemcpy` as you have shown it is not an asynchronous operation; it blocks the CPU thread.  Therefore, you should at most have one kernel call outstanding at a time.

Comment: "program stops working" means that window appears: "Apolar.exe has stopped working. Windows is checking to the solution of the problem."

Comment: That looks like a segmentation fault or other similar (host-code) problem in your program.  It may not have anything to do with CUDA.

Comment: you absolutely right, when I commented cuda kernel, it didn't work as well . Sorry for that, I am closing question

Comment: Yes, question was not stupid. But I had to check such simple thing before posting the question...